# How to sort a list based on the latest occurrence of its elements?

Tags: python, data-structures

I have the following list

```
list_  = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'c']
```

Here, we could see that , 'c' was added the **latest**, followed by 'a' and 'b'.
So the resultant output i need is as follows :

```
final = ['b', 'a', 'c']   ('b' was the oldest update, and 'c' being the latest update, after not considering duplicate entries)
```

My approach would be the following:

```
list_ = list_[::-1]
list_ = [*dict.fromkeys(list_)][::-1]
```

Is there an even efficient approach? This list can be huge so efficiency is important.
Is there any `dequeue` based approach like storing this in dequeue first and then processing in an  efficient manner?

Comment: `list(reversed(dict.fromkeys(reversed(list_))))` can reduce two unnecessary copies.

Comment: It would be much easier to maintain this "list of adds" while you are building the main list.  (You mention that things are "added" to the list).  So why don't you maintain a second data structure while you are building?